# PHP shell_exec not accepting '>' parameter

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to execute a shell command from PHP with `shell_exec()`:

```
$output = shell_exec('python test.py > test.txt');
```

When I run `python test.py > test.txt` from the command line it works. When I try to do the same via PHP, no `test.txt` file is created and the command appears not to run.

`shell_exec()` works fine when I don't use `>`, e.g.

```
$output = shell_exec('python test.py');
echo $output;
```

I am using PHP 5.3.6, (not in safe mode). Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: Does your Apache/PHP user have permission to write into the current directory and/or `test.txt`? Take a look into your `error.log`.

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions/SELinux context on the dir and file?

Comment: Set permissions to 777 on directory and contents and didn't work. I don't get any error messages either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a sanity test?  Something like this

```
<?php
shell_exec('echo blah > /tmp/blah.txt;');
if(trim(file_get_contents('/tmp/blah.txt')) == 'blah')
    echo 'It works' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Something is wrong' . PHP_EOL;
```

Also, worse case senario, a simple workaround should do the trick.

```
<?php
file_put_contents('test.txt', exec('python test.py'));
```

If you need buffering for large file contents you can get that w/ [fwrite et al.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Who knows, you might not be writing to the directory you intend to, try putting in an absolute path to *test.txt*.